# How I can create a table with oracle but with small characters?

Tags: oracle, quoted-identifier

How I can create a table with oracle but with small characters, when I create a table with small characters it converts auto to capital characters.

Comment: what do you want to do? give us more information please

Comment: Record is getting converted to upper case or table columns are getting converted into lower upper case?

Comment: when i execute this query "create table t (
 a number,
 b varchar2(10)
)"

Comment: the name of the table and columns became capital characters not small characters

Comment: and I use Oracle SQL Developer Data Modeler

Comment: @user1384279 I doubt you can change that, Oracle creates tables, columns in upper case.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Folding (non-quoted) table names to upper case is required by the ANSI SQL standard.

You *can* create tables (and columns) with lowercase names using a quoted identifier (again this follows the SQL standard):

```
CREATE TABLE "foo" 
(
   "id"          integer,
   "SomeColumn"  varchar(100)
);
```

I would however strongly advise you, to ***not*** do that.

Once you have your tables created that way, you have to ***always*** use double quotes because any non-quoted name will (following the rules for SQL identifiers) again be folded to upper-case and thus won't match the name as it is stored in the system catalogs.

Therefor the following statement will **not** work:

```
SELECT id, somecolumn FROM foo;
```

You have to use a quoted identifier:

```
SELECT "id", "SomeColumn" FROM "foo";
```

For more details on (quoted) identifiers, please read the chapter [Database Object Naming Rules](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Database-Object-Names-and-Qualifiers.html#GUID-75337742-67FD-4EC0-985F-741C93D918DA) in the manual.

Comment: agreed with a horse with no name' I've seen and had to debug production code that used this, as the guys who wrote the app were Java developers that for some reason LOVE using camel case table and column names, as that's the way they type identifiers in Java. it's an absolute nightmare to maintain this in oracle. you almost feel like throwing the keyboard through the monitor when you see hundreds of views that all contain mixed case columns + view names and you get asked to tune some sql against them.

Comment: Agreed, great explanation - short and sweet and directly to the point!

Answer (score 0):

Enclose table name in quotation marks (`"`). Also create your table like this

```
create table "t" ( a number, b varchar2(10) );
```

Now your table name is `t` in lowercase. You have to use quotation marks always, when you access your table. For example

```
select * from "t";
```

You can use same construct for other objects (columns, indexes, ...).

Anyway, SQL is case insensitive, you need a good reason to use case dependent object names.